# Scala way to do apache commons lang3 Validate?

Tags: java, scala

What is the Scala way to accomplish the same as apache commons lang3 [Validate](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html)? i.e. the validation aimed for user input validation as opposed to coding errors via assertions where failing the condition would lead to an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) e.g.

```
/**
 * Returns the newly created file only if the user entered a valid path.
 * @param path input path where to store the new file
 * @param fileName name of the file to be created in directory path
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException when the input path doesn't exist.  
 */
public File createFile(File path, String fileName) {
    // make sure that the path exists before creating the file
    // TODO: is there a way to do this in Scala without the need for 3rd party libraries
    org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate.isTrue(path.exists(), "Illegal input path '" + path.getAbsolutePath() + "', it doesn't exist")
    // now it is safe to create the file ...
    File result = new File(path, fileName)
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Is `org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate(path.exists(), "Illegal input path '" + path.getAbsolutePath() + "', it doesn't exist")` even valid? What method are you calling? Anyway, question unclear. Are you trying to *call* commons-validate? Or are you trying to write your own similar validation function in Scala?

Comment: Looking at [the docs you linked to](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/Validate.html#Validate()) the constructor for `Validate` is described with "This class should not normally be instantiated" ... and it doesn't take any parameters.  So @vptheron is correct asking for clarification about what method you are calling, since what you have doesn't appear to be a method in the `org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate` class that you linked to.

Comment: Sorry indeed mea culpa now is updated. I'm getting too used to the Scala apply

Comment: I don't want to use a third party library in this case apache commons lang when there is a nice way to accomplish the same in Scala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By coincidence I just found out that `require` would be the method of choice in Scala e.g.

```
/**
 * Returns the newly created file only if the user entered a valid path.
 * @param path input path where to store the new file
 * @param fileName name of the file to be created in directory path
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException when the input path doesn't exist.  
 */
def createFile(path: File, fileName: String) : File = {
    require(path.exists, s"""Illegal input path "${path.getAbsolutePath()}", it doesn't exist""")
    // now it is safe to create the file ...
    val result = new File(path, fileName)
    // ...
    result
}
```

Comment: This is OT, I didn't ask in my OP whether throwing an exception is a terrible idea or not, I asked what is the would be replacement of Apache commons Validate in Scala. The example is simply an example of validating user input.